# Why i cant get real content by php+curl from opencart?

Tags: php, curl, xmlhttprequest, opencart

i need auto buy script for opencart. Registration and cart work good. i found XHR post requests to save results, but when i try to checkout order i get this error:

```html
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://some_url.com/index.php?route=checkout/payment_method/save');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'payment_method=pp_pro&comment=&agree=1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

print $data;

{"error":{"warning":"Warning: Payment method required!"}}
```

Comment: Which part of that doesnt work, and what do you expect to happen? Be specific and go into detail.

Comment: index.php?route=checkout/payment_address - back me real info.
but next steps back me only templates.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart API is the solution to your problem. Watch the video below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bc2govdEiuA

The OpenCart API allows your application to access current data within OpenCart. Through the API, several common operations can be performed on OpenCart. Operations include:

create — Creates with the specified parameters.
For example, you can add products to the cart as given by OpenCart API post request of products or product_id at
/index.php?route=api/cart/add
read — Retrieves information about the specified object.
query — Retrieves objects that match specified criteria.
update — Updates elements of an existing object.
upsert — Updates elements of an existing object if it exists. If the object does not exist, one is created using the supplied parameters.

https://webocreation.com/blog/opencart-api-documentation-to-create-read-query-update-and-upsert

Comment: I want to buy not in my shop, where i can get token to work with api?

Comment: {"error":"Warning: No match for Username and\/or Password."}

Comment: In the video above shows at around 2:30min 
https://youtu.be/bc2govdEiuA?t=149 

Admin >> System >> Users >> API where you can create them.

Comment: Ask your Administrator to provide access to API users, else I don't think there is turn around :)